# Can you help me to understand this Java SE code?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jtable

I try to pass a resultset to a `JTable`, and I find this code but I can't understand how it works, expecially this part of code:

```
while(rst.next()){
            Object [] riga = new Object [numeroColumns];

            for(int y = 0; y<numeroColumns; y++){
                riga [y] = rst.getObject(y+1);
            }
            model.addRow(riga);
        }
```

Why we put y+1 in the `getObject` method?

This is the complete code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datazanzariere?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "admin");
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rst = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM riepilogoordine");
        ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rst.getMetaData();
        int numeroColumns = rsMd.getColumnCount();

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.jTable1.setModel(model);

        for (int x = 1; x <= numeroColumns; x++){
            model.addColumn(rsMd.getColumnLabel(x));
        }

        while(rst.next()){
            Object [] riga = new Object [numeroColumns];

            for(int y = 0; y<numeroColumns; y++){
                riga [y] = rst.getObject(y+1);
            }
            model.addRow(riga);
        }

    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ce){
        ce.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because for `ResultSet` column index starts from 1 instead of 0.
So in `getObject()` index param should start from 1

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject(int)) states "columnIndex - the first column is 1, the second is 2, …". So the code is fetching rows 1 to `numeroColumns` (inclusive) with `getObject` and putting them in indices 0 to `numeroColumns-1` of `riga`.